# How to import SignalR in React Component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, signalr

I have used **create-react-app** to scaffold the initial react application.

My **DashBoard** component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'signalr';

class Dashboard extends Component {
   constructor(props) {    
   super(props);
   var connection = $.hubConnection('http://[address]:[port]');
   var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('[hubname]');   

    // atempt connection, and handle errors
    connection.start()
    .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });
}

  render() {
    return (...);
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Now I get the below error from SignalR saying jQuery is not added, but I have imported it in the line above:

> Error: jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before
>   the SignalR client JavaScript file.

If I comment out import "signalr"; jQuery gets loaded correctly and i can access the `$` inside the module. Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you show how you load your script in your HTML?

Comment: you can see the `create-react-app` for that.

Comment: Why don't you do this: `import $ from 'jquery';` and then `import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: It doesn't make any change.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030002/how-to-load-signalr-js-in-webpack-inside-angular-2

Answer (score 27):

This is how we do it now (year 2020) with the new package @microsoft/signalr.
We use Redux, but you don't have to use Redux to be able to utilize this method.

If you are using @microsoft/signalr package instead of @aspnet/signalr, then this is how you can set it up. This is our working code in prod:

```
import {
  JsonHubProtocol,
  HubConnectionState,
  HubConnectionBuilder,
  LogLevel
} from '@microsoft/signalr';

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const startSignalRConnection = async connection => {
  try {
    await connection.start();
    console.assert(connection.state === HubConnectionState.Connected);
    console.log('SignalR connection established');
  } catch (err) {
    console.assert(connection.state === HubConnectionState.Disconnected);
    console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err);
    setTimeout(() => startSignalRConnection(connection), 5000);
  }
};

// Set up a SignalR connection to the specified hub URL, and actionEventMap.
// actionEventMap should be an object mapping event names, to eventHandlers that will
// be dispatched with the message body.
export const setupSignalRConnection = (connectionHub, actionEventMap = {}, getAccessToken) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const options = {
    logMessageContent: isDev,
    logger: isDev ? LogLevel.Warning : LogLevel.Error,
    accessTokenFactory: () => getAccessToken(getState())
  };
  // create the connection instance
  // withAutomaticReconnect will automatically try to reconnect
  // and generate a new socket connection if needed
  const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .withHubProtocol(new JsonHubProtocol())
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

  // Note: to keep the connection open the serverTimeout should be
  // larger than the KeepAlive value that is set on the server
  // keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds default is 15000 and we are using default
  // serverTimeoutInMilliseconds default is 30000 and we are using 60000 set below
  connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 60000;

  // re-establish the connection if connection dropped
  connection.onclose(error => {
    console.assert(connection.state === HubConnectionState.Disconnected);
    console.log('Connection closed due to error. Try refreshing this page to restart the connection', error);
  });

  connection.onreconnecting(error => {
    console.assert(connection.state === HubConnectionState.Reconnecting);
    console.log('Connection lost due to error. Reconnecting.', error);
  });

  connection.onreconnected(connectionId => {
    console.assert(connection.state === HubConnectionState.Connected);
    console.log('Connection reestablished. Connected with connectionId', connectionId);
  });

  startSignalRConnection(connection);

  connection.on('OnEvent', res => {
    const eventHandler = actionEventMap[res.eventType];
    eventHandler && dispatch(eventHandler(res));
  });

  return connection;
};
```

Then you would call like the following. Please note that this a pseudo code. You may have to call it differently depending on your project setup.

```
import { setupSignalRConnection } from 'fileAbove.js';

const connectionHub = '/hub/service/url/events';

export const setupEventsHub = setupSignalRConnection(connectionHub, {
  onMessageEvent: someMethod
}, getAccessToken);

export default () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setupEventsHub); // dispatch is coming from Redux
};
```

Let me know if it helped by up-voting. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to handle multiple event handlers in `setupSignalRConnection`

Comment: @Akhilesh, yes, that is an object I am passing with one property called "onMessageEvent". You can add as many properties as you like to that object.

Comment: `onMessageEvent` is the action for the event `OnEvent` (i.e one to many) I am asking how do you handle multiple events like 'Event A', 'Event B', etc with their corresponding handlers (i.e. many to many)

Comment: @Akhilesh, If I understood your question correctly, my previous answer is still valid.
"onMessageEvent" is just an arbitrary event. You can rename that to anything you want.
So if you have multiple events to handle, you need something like this:
{ onMessageEvent: someMethod, EventA: eventAHandler, EventB: eventBHandler }.
I hope it helps.

Comment: How do we stop the connection on let's say logout?

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE:** Please note that if you are using Redux in your ReactJS app, the solution below is not necessarily the best solution. [It is better to implement signalR as a middleware. You can find the best answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625267/where-to-put-signalr-hub-in-react-redux-app/52653795#52653795)

If you are not using Redux, or you still want to implement it in a React component, then read on:
For people that are using the latest version of signalR (core v2.1), since jQuery is not a dependency of signalR any more, you can import it like:

```
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

**NOTE:** there is now a newer version of signalr available (@microsoft/signalr) that requires a different setup. This solution only works with @aspnet/signalr. (**UPDATE June 2020**)

And then use it like:

```
signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
```

Here is an example:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { string } from 'prop-types';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

class SignalR extends PureComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.connection = null;
    this.onNotifReceived = this.onNotifReceived.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const protocol = new signalR.JsonHubProtocol();

    const transport = signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets;

    const options = {
      transport,
      logMessageContent: true,
      logger: signalR.LogLevel.Trace,
      accessTokenFactory: () => this.props.accessToken,
    };

    // create the connection instance
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.props.connectionHub, options)
      .withHubProtocol(protocol)
      .build();

    this.connection.on('DatabaseOperation', this.onNotifReceived);
    this.connection.on('DownloadSession', this.onNotifReceived);
    this.connection.on('UploadSession', this.onNotifReceived);

    this.connection.start()
      .then(() => console.info('SignalR Connected'))
      .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.connection.stop();
  }

  onNotifReceived (res) {
    console.info('Yayyyyy, I just received a notification!!!', res);
  }

  render () {
    return <span />;
  };
};

SignalR.propTypes = {
  connectionHub: string.isRequired,
  accessToken: string.isRequired
};

export default SignalR;
```

**UPDATE**: in 2020, you can use "withAutomaticReconnect()":

```
  const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .withHubProtocol(new JsonHubProtocol())
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
```

Comment: will this work when on my backend is Web Api 2 (.NET Framework 4.6.1) ?

Comment: @mardok, I am not sure about v2. But I am using v2.1 and it works like a charm. You might have to use `'@aspnet/signalr-client'` for v2.

Comment: @xeiton How do you know this?

Comment: In my case, I faced a problem in connection initially using the above code and after setting the "skipNegotiation: true," in the connection options it worked.

Comment: I am getting `'HubConnectionBuilder' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: @CarlosGarcia what version of this package are you using? Could it be because you are using the newer package of signalR from "@microsoft/signalr" instead of "@aspnet/signalr"? If yes, then the way you should set this up will be slightly different.

Comment: To be honest, this "updated" answer cost me a lot of trouble. Clearly this is a fast moving library. I used the part of your snippet to set up the connection and it cost me HOURS once I ran it in a hosted environment to solve many connection/protocol related issues. My advice for SignalR: use the official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: You should always FIRST consult the documentation and use StackOverflow for troubleshooting or finding ideas. This way you won't blame others for your own mistakes. You need to check the version of package you are using against whats being discussed here. Also you can't just copy parts of my code and paste it into yours and expect it to work. You need investigate the differences in your project setup and adjust your code accordingly. Not nice of you to Down-Vote someone who is trying to help others.

Comment: @xeiton - I obviously started with the official documentation but ran into an issue and landed here. Your "you need to check the versions" and "you can't just copy code" parts are really not helpful at all. You don't clearly state client AND server package versions but you do add 3 UPDATE blocks on your issue. Imho, there should be a rule to NOT update old  answers. It gives the false impression of being kept in sync with library changes. In conclusion, I didn't find your solution useful at all, hence the down-vote, it's how SO works.

Answer (score 7):

What I figured out **Signalr** has dependency on `jQuery`. For some reason `import $ from 'jquery'` doesn't set `window.jQuery`. That's why need to do it explicitly.

I solved the issue this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
require('signalr');

class Dashboard extends Component {
   // .....   
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: This is not the case anymore as from ASP.NET Core 2.1, SignalR dropped the jQuery dependency. https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt829706

Comment: @xeiton you can use this: `import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';`

Comment: @MarkSzabo Will this work when on my backend is Web Api 2 (.NET Framework 4.6.1) ?

Comment: @mardok Good question, I'm not sure. Try to install the nuget package, and check what the latest allowed version is!

Answer (score 1):

Check out SignalR no jQuery

```js
npm i -D signalr-no-jquery
import { hubConnection } from 'signalr-no-jquery';

const connection = hubConnection('http://[address]:[port]', options);
const hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('hubNameString');

// set up event listeners i.e. for incoming "message" event
hubProxy.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});

// connect
connection.start({ jsonp: true })
  .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
  .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-no-jquery

Comment: Not able to make server call from client using this.
publicHubProxy.invoke('getAllGroups'), getting error as Error: Send failed