# Where to put SignalR hub in React/Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, signalr

I'm designing a React website using Redux as the state store, which is primarily to display the current population of items to the user, using live updates to update the item population using SignalR.

The way I wanted to do this was to have SignalR send item update messages both to initialise the starting population when you connect to the server hub, as well as updates via the same message type as time goes on. I would have a function that takes a SignalR message and converts it to a Redux action and dispatches to Redux store, which would then use the action to update the state and then the UI.

So the idea is

> 1) Connect to SignalR server hub, with client handler function set up
>   for ItemUpdate messages
>
> 2) When server receives Connect() from the
>   client, it sends ItemUpdate messages for all current items in the
>   population
>
> 3) The client receives these messages from SignalR,
>   transforms to actions and dispatches to the Redux store
>
> 4) Redux
>   updates the store based on the new item information and the UI
>   displays it
>
> 5) Server realises an item has been added or updated and
>   sends a new ItemUpdate message for the update to the client
>
> 6) Repeat

However I am not sure of exactly where I should keep the hub singleton as this seems counter to React/Redux design. Can someone advise on the best way to do this?

My main app

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'rxjs';
import store from './store/index';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

My store creation file

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import signalRMiddleware from '../signalr/middleware';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(signalRMiddleware));
export default store;
```

My middleware for outbound SignalR messages to the server (commented out as I do not have access to the hub object I need for this to work

```
export default function signalRMiddleware(store: any) {
    return (next: any) => (action: any) => {
        if (action.signalR) {
            switch (action.type) {
                default:
                    {
                        //const myCurrentState = store.getState().objectWithinState;
                        //_hub.server.methodOnTheServer2(action.type, myCurrentState);
                    }
            }
        }
        return next(action);
    }
}
```

Now for the incoming messages... this is the shell of a signalR start function I got from an online example - not yet implemented as I do not have the hub and connection yet and not sure where this should go

```
export function signalRStart(store: any, callback: Function) {
    _hub = $.connection.myHubName;

    _hub.client.firstClientFunction = (p1: any) => {
        store.dispatch({ type: "SERVER_CALLED_ME", a: p1 });
    }

    _hub.client.secondClientFunction = (p1: string, p2: string) => {
            store.dispatch({ type: "SERVER_CALLED_ME_2", value: p1 + p2 });
        }
    }

    $.connection.hub.start(() => callback());
}
```

And this is the example given on the website I found the code on to tie it all together, however I do not see how this can integrate with React/Redux as in my main Index page, I have to pass the created store to the Provider component and so I cannot put the hub creation below this, as you need the hub for the signalr middleware component which is passed into the store creation

```
let _hub;

let store = createStore(
  todoApp,
  // applyMiddleware() tells createStore() how to handle middleware
  applyMiddleware(signalRMiddleware)
)

// Make sure signalr is connected
signalRStart(store, () => {
    render((...),
    document.getElementById("app-container"));
});
```

Can someone advise on the best way to integrate SignalR into my React/Redux app?

Comment: I think SignalR should update the redux store only, so your app should not have SignalR -> React integrations at all only: SignalR -> Redux -> React

Comment: Does that mean I should create the signalR hub object in the initial store creation and keep it in the Redux store for the lifetime of the app?

Comment: @NZJames, did you figure out solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating a SignalR Middleware, which instantiated the connection and started it at that point, setting up the listeners at that point for incoming signalr messages. In the middleware handler, it then handles the outgoing signalR messages via the redux actions.

Comment: Hey @NZJames , Do you mind providing a code snippet of your final solution for us? we all would really appreciate it, and I am sure it will help many people in future. Thanks!

Comment: @NZJames yes please, a code segment from your solution would help a lot. I also need something like this.

Comment: @terett, I added my own middle-ware so hopefully it would help others.

Answer (score 16):

**For people that may find this thread in future.**

This is my custom middleware that only establishes the connection, and registers the handlers. Please note that I only would like to receive data, and not interested in sending data.

```
import {
  JsonHubProtocol,
  HttpTransportType,
  HubConnectionBuilder,
  LogLevel
} from '@aspnet/signalr'; // version 1.0.4

// action for user authentication and receiving the access_token
import { USER_SIGNED_IN } from '../actions/auth';

const onNotifReceived = res => {
  console.log('****** NOTIFICATION ******', res);
};

const startSignalRConnection = connection => connection.start()
  .then(() => console.info('SignalR Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));

const signalRMiddleware = ({ getState }) => next => async (action) => {
  // register signalR after the user logged in
  if (action.type === USER_SIGNED_IN) {
    const urlRoot = (window.appConfig || {}).URL_ROOT;
    const connectionHub = `${urlRoot}/api/service/hub`;

    const protocol = new JsonHubProtocol();

    // let transport to fall back to to LongPolling if it needs to
    const transport = HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

    const options = {
      transport,
      logMessageContent: true,
      logger: LogLevel.Trace,
      accessTokenFactory: () => action.user.access_token
    };

    // create the connection instance
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
      .withHubProtocol(protocol)
      .build();

    // event handlers, you can use these to dispatch actions to update your Redux store
    connection.on('OperationProgress', onNotifReceived);
    connection.on('UploadProgress', onNotifReceived);
    connection.on('DownloadProgress', onNotifReceived);

    // re-establish the connection if connection dropped
    connection.onclose(() => setTimeout(startSignalRConnection(connection), 5000));

    startSignalRConnection(connection);
  }

  return next(action);
};

export default signalRMiddleware;
```

And inside my store.js file

```
import signalRMiddleware from '../middlewares/signalRMiddleware';

...

createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(signalRMiddleware)));
```

**UPDATE June 2020**
This is how we do it now with the new package @microsoft/signalr
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162742/10232269
This is not using the middleware method. We use Redux, but you don't have to use Redux to utilize this method.

Comment: Do you also have code to invoke methods on Server end?

Comment: @Xeiton By chance have you got an example on github? Thanks for this by the way.

Comment: do you have an example for signalr (not aspnet/signalr) library? the one used with .net framework not .net core. Thank you!

Comment: You can see this post for implementation with the new package @microsoft/signalr. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162742/10232269

Comment: @xeiton What to do when there are multiple `connectionHub`s (more than one hub urls)?

Comment: @Akhilesh,  I would say create multiple instances of "connection" with the other hub urls. The new "connection" instances will be able to handle new events on those hub urls.

Answer (score 7):

Per the Redux FAQ, [the right place for websockets and other similar connections is in Redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live).

[Here is a list of existing websocket middle-wares](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/5ecb1e251766c20318bdc3b4f75363d2c4e4ab0a/middleware-sockets-adapters.md). You can look at the source code of a couple of them and very easily get an idea of how to implement your own custom middle-ware:

A middleware can dispatch actions. Here's an example of what a socket middleware might look like, and dispatching an action that it listens for:

```
const createMySocketMiddleware = (url) => {
    return storeAPI => {
        let socket = createMyWebsocket(url);

        socket.on("message", (message) => {
            storeAPI.dispatch({
                type : "SOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED",
                payload : message
            });
        });

        return next => action => {
            if(action.type == "SEND_WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE") {
                socket.send(action.payload);
                return;
            }

            return next(action);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to apply this middleware to your redux store

```
let store = createStore(
    some_reducer,
    applyMiddleware(createMySocketMiddleware)
)
```

Later, in your app. This is an action creator

```
const sendSocketMessage = message => ({
    type : "SEND_WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE",
    payload : message
}
```

Add a button in your component to dispatch an action via websockets

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.sendSocketMessage("This goes to the server");
    }
}

export default connect(null, {sendSocketMessage})(MyComponent)
```

Comment: I'm confused, is your nesting of functions correct ?  
According to <https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware> the correct signature is:  
`applyMiddleware( storeAPI => next => action => { ... } )`  
but your structure is:  
`applyMiddleware( (url) => storeAPI => next => action => { ... } )`

Comment: All those signatures are ultimately passed as a parameter to applyMiddleware. So as long as the end result is the same you can curry the funcs as many times as you like.