# react and SignalR issues

Tags: .net, reactjs, signalr

I'm trying to build a chat application with react and SignalR. I tried to edit the following code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

class Chat extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            nick: '',
            message: '',
            messages: [],
            hubConnection: null,
        };

    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const nick = window.prompt('Your name:', 'John');

        //const hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:5000/chat'); 
        //Said deprecated

        const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://localhost:5000/chat').build();

        this.setState({ hubConnection, nick }, () => {
            this.state.hubConnection
                .start()
                .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
                .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

            this.state.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', (nick, receivedMessage) => {
                const text = `${nick}: ${receivedMessage}`;
                const messages = this.state.messages.concat([text]);
                this.setState({ messages });
            });
        });
    }


    sendMessage = () => {
        this.state.hubConnection
            .invoke('sendToAll', this.state.nick, this.state.message)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));

        this.setState({ message: '' });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.message}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })}
                />

                <button onClick={this.sendMessage}>Send</button>

                <div>
                    {this.state.messages.map((message, index) => (
                        <span style={{ display: 'block' }} key={index}> {message} </span>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Chat;
```

The first issue I faced was, const hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:5000/chat'); seemed deprecated.

Following are some of the errors that I'm recieving.
Can someone please let me know a newly updated post where I can refer to build this. I didn't find any.

If I'm not using the SignalR, is there anything alse that I can refer to with React to implement the chat visibility

[image]

Comment: what? like socket.io?? http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can import specific modules from SignalR (v1.0.4):

```
import {
  JsonHubProtocol,
  HttpTransportType,
  HubConnectionBuilder,
  LogLevel
} from '@aspnet/signalr'; // version 1.0.4
```

And this is how you can create the Hub:

```
// create the connection instance
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
  .withHubProtocol(protocol)
  .build();
```

I hope that helps. [Here is a reference you can take a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671969/10232269)