# SignalR from React: 'HubConnectionBuilder' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, signalr

First of all, I am very new to JS and React. I am following this question: [How to import SignalR in React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190574/how-to-import-signalr-in-react-component)
I guess it is a very simple thing, but i cannot figure out where is the problem.

The error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 49:28:  'HubConnectionBuilder' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 52:28:  'JsonHubProtocol' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 53:25:  'LogLevel' is not defined              no-undef
```

My package.json:

```
  ...
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
  ...
```

My App.js

```
...
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

class App extends React.Component {
  super(props);
  constructor(props) {
    this.connectionHub = "Endpoint=https://<signalrname>.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=<token>;Version=1.0;"
    this.accessToken = "<token>";

  ...

  this.connection = null;
  this.onNotifReceived = this.onNotifReceived.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount () {
    const protocol = new signalR.JsonHubProtocol();

    const transport = signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets;

    const options = {
      transport,
      logMessageContent: true,
      logger: signalR.LogLevel.Trace,
      accessTokenFactory: () => this.accessToken,
    };

    // create the connection instance
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.connectionHub, options)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .withHubProtocol(new JsonHubProtocol())
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();

    this.connection.on('DatabaseOperation', this.onNotifReceived);
    this.connection.on('DownloadSession', this.onNotifReceived);
    this.connection.on('UploadSession', this.onNotifReceived);

    this.connection.start()
      .then(() => console.info('SignalR Connected'))
      .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));
  }

  ...
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At all the places where you are using "HubConnectionBuilder", "JsonHubProtocol" and "LogLevel", you'll have to use it as:

```
signalR.HubConnectionBuilder
signalR.JsonHubProtocol
signalR.LogLevel
```

Because all these are exported by @aspnet/signalr library.

[image]

Or for a more better approach you could replace

```
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

with

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder, JsonHubProtocol, LogLevel } from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

Doing this you'd not need to `signalR.xyz` every time.

Comment: Thank you @Parth! I also had to change to ` @microsoft/signalr` instead of `aspnet` so that it accepted `withAutomaticReconnect`